# How do you mock default timezone during unit test?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

During unit test, I would like to temporary mock the default timezone to specific country. This is what I do currently, by using global variable.

### Application code

```
import Foundation

var _TIME_ZONE_FOR_UNIT_TEST: TimeZone? = nil

extension TimeZone {
    static func current() -> TimeZone {
        if let _TIME_ZONE_FOR_UNIT_TEST = _TIME_ZONE_FOR_UNIT_TEST {
            return _TIME_ZONE_FOR_UNIT_TEST
        } else {
            return TimeZone.current
        }
    }
}
```

### Unit test

```
func testToDayResolutionInCuba() throws {
    let cubaTimeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Havana")!
    
    _TIME_ZONE_FOR_UNIT_TEST = cubaTimeZone
    defer {
        _TIME_ZONE_FOR_UNIT_TEST = nil
    }
    
    ...
    
    // ReminderUtils.toDayResolution is depending on TimeZone.current()
    let timestampWithoutTime = ReminderUtils.toDayResolution(timeMillis)
```

---

Although it works, I do not like such a way as

1. Global variable is used
2. Extra runtime cost for the `if` check

Is there a better way for me to perform unit test for a specific timezone?

Comment: If the application gets the time zone by saying `TimeZone.current`, then the way to test is to mock TimeZone.

Comment: The app is using custom `TimeZone.current()` (Not `TimeZone.current`) so that we can have full control on what is being returned. Can you kindly elaborate more on how can we "mock" TimeZone?

Comment: I'm saying use `current`. — Do you understand what mocking is? The "if" happens just once when the app launches. If this is the app we just use the real TimeZone. If this is a test we use a mock object that has the same interface so you can control what is returned from `current`.

Comment: Change the method signature so you can inject a timezone, and have `.current` as the default.  Then in the unit test you can inject whatever zone you want to test against, which will also make you test more flexible.

Comment: Or change the method signature so you can inject a TimeZone-like object to which the `.current` message can be sent; in the real app that would be TimeZone, but in the test it would be your mock. — But if you want detailed help you need to provide actual details from your app code. For example if the goal is to test `ReminderUtils.toDayResolution(timeMillis)` you need to show us that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This solution doesn't work on iOS 17, as `Timezone.current` no longer reaches to `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone` in order to swizzle it.**

---

`TimeZone` is a direct wrapper over Objective-C's `NSTimeZone`, and `TimeZone.current` corresponds to `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone`.

Thus, you can mock/stub `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone` with any mocking framework. This will help you get rid of the nasty `if` from your codebase.

Comment: Thanks for tips! I post the code snippet to show how it is being done exactly.

Comment: It seems iOS 17 broke the ability to do this. `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone` can no longer be swizzled and be picked up by `TimeZone.current`

Comment: Thanks @RafaelNobre for pointing it out, I did some debugging to see what happens on iOS 17, sadly seems that swizzling is no longer an option...

Answer (score 2):

Mocking can be done by mutating `NSTimeZone.default`

```
// Cuba will advance its clock by 1 hour, during 2021-03-14 00:00 am. This means during 2021-03-13 23:59 pm, after
// next 1 second, the time will be 2021-03-14 01:00 am.
func testToDayResolutionInCuba() throws {
    let cubaTimeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Havana")!
    let oldDefault = NSTimeZone.default
    NSTimeZone.default = cubaTimeZone
    defer {
        NSTimeZone.default = oldDefault
    }
    
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = 2021
    dateComponents.month = 3
    dateComponents.day = 14
    dateComponents.hour = 0
    dateComponents.minute = 0
    dateComponents.second = 0
    
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
    
    let timeMillis = date.timeMillis
    
    let timestampWithoutTime = ReminderUtils.toDayResolution(timeMillis)
    
    let dateWithoutTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(timestampWithoutTime/1000))
    let result = calendar.dateComponents(in: cubaTimeZone, from: dateWithoutTime)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(2021, result.year)
    XCTAssertEqual(3, result.month)
    XCTAssertEqual(14, result.day)
    XCTAssertEqual(1, result.hour)
    XCTAssertEqual(0, result.minute)
    XCTAssertEqual(0, result.second)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979424.

Since iOS 17, `Timezone.current` no longer reaches to `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone`, so swizzling `NSTimeZone` does not work anymore.

But there is a way.
The new `TimeZone` implementation prefers the TZ environment value.

Darwin's `setenv` with `1` param to force override if anything was set previously, allows to do that during the runtime by e.g.

```swift
setenv("TZ", identifier, 1)
```

It does not work on its own as internally `TimeZone` is using caching machinery.
But we can trick the invalidation process by calling:

```swift
CFTimeZoneResetSystem()
```

All of this seems to be working well in the case of e.g. unit tests:

```
func test() {
    setenv("TZ", "America/New_York", 1)
    CFTimeZoneResetSystem()

    print(TimeZone.current) // America/New_York (fixed)
    print(TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent) // America/New_York (autoupdatingCurrent)
}
```